# Change the value of Limit x,y in mysql_fetch_array statement after every echo?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have:

```
$q = 1;
$w = 10
$result_new= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events LIMIT $q, $w");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_new))
{
   echo $row['title'];
}
```

**Is there any way to change the value of $q so that it is $q++ after every loop of the while statement?**

**If I put it in the while statement:**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_new))
{
   echo $row['title'];
   $q++
}
```

**It doesn't work because the value of $q has already been set.**

Comment: What are you trying to do? That's not how you use `LIMIT`.

Comment: did u try with `$q+=$w`? just after while

Comment: he is trying to show the database output in multipe pages.

Comment: Well I am trying to get $q to change from 1 to 2 to 3... after every loop of the while it increases by one, so that the limit changes from: 1,10 to 2,10 to 3,10, and so on.

Comment: but we don't see why you would need to change your query between fetching each row, while you still have not fetched all the results you queried earlier.

Comment: @Adrien I am actually just trying to fix an error in an Ajax statement, the values $q and $w are retained from a database, and a problem has come up that if more than 1 update it made to the database before the reload request can be made to load the new rows, it will not recognize the change in the $q value because it is defined as the old value in the mysql_query statement.

Comment: @Adrien, the results are fetched from the database, I just didn't include that code in this example because it does not add to my question. The variables are actually found in a php query, stored as javascript variables where they are modified, and then sent via ajax to the php page using GET, and then this function runs.

Comment: This file load how many time?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong! You need to give the right values when you're doing the query. Then when you get your result set, you have `$w` rows waiting to be fetched with for example `mysql_fetch_array`.

If, for some reason, you don't know how many rows you want when you start out, you have to make a second query to get the remaining rows.

`LIMIT $q, $w` works in such a way that `$q` decides the start position and `$w` decides the number of records to fetch.

`LIMIT 0, 10` which is equivalent to just `LIMIT 10` gets  the first 10 rows of the result set.

`LIMIT 10, 10` gives the next 10. `LIMIT 20, 10` gives the next 10 after that. In othe words, the first parameter is the start position starting from 0, and the second parameter is the **number of rows**, not the "end position".

**Edit:** Suggestion after new information.

```
$num_pages = 4;    // Get 4 pages...
$page_size = 10;   // ... with 10 rows each


for($i=0; $i<$num_pages; $i++){
    $offset = $i * $page_size;

    $result_new= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events LIMIT $offset, $page_size");

    // Add one since MySQL counts from 0 but humans usually from 1
    echo "<h1>Page ".$i+1."</h1>";

    // Loop through one page
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_new)){
        echo $row['title'];
    }
}
```

It's still not really efficient to do more SQL queries than you need, so you can get it all in one query, with a little trick. This code should output the same thing as my code above.

```
$num_pages = 4;    // Get 4 pages...
$page_size = 10;   // ... with 10 rows each
$position = 0;     // Position counter used in the loop
$page = 1;         // Since this will not be used in DB calls, we can start from 1

$total_rows = $num_pages * $page_size;

$result_new= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events LIMIT $total_rows");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_new)){
    // Little trick to check if we're at the beginning of a page.
    if($position%$page_size == 0){
        echo "<h1>Page ".$page."</h1>";
        $page++;
    }

    echo $row['title'];

    $position++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

based on your comment, if you REALLY want to update your query between each row:

```
$q = 0;
$w = 10;

for ( $i = 0; $i < $w; i++ )
{
    $result_new= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events LIMIT $q, 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_new);
    echo $row['title'];

    $q++;
}
```

here, we query 1 row (no need to get more since we will not read more results), then we update the query to retrieve the next row.

*(the above code is particularly not efficient)*

Comment: I'm on the fringe of giving this a bad rating just because it's so inefficient and not something that should be taught to unsuspecting beginners, even if the inefficiency is pointed out. Besides, you copied the OP's mistake to think that `$q = 1` gives the first record. It doesn't – `$q = 0` does.

Comment: you are right, that is pretty bad code. anyway, that's the best i can come up with the informations given by the OP. feel free to give a bad rating, and post your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use for loop to increment the value of $q.. and In foor loop you can put your query..